# Ioerror importing csv file showing .csv file does not exits

Tags: python, csv

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/nasif/Desktop/ashik_Thesis/wbpc_data.csv")
```

i am working with this data:https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wpbc.data

i have downloaded it as a text file and then converting it as a csv file.
But it's not working showing error.

```
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-118820404033> in <module>()
     12 
     13 
---> 14 df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/nasif/Desktop/ashik_Thesis/wbpc_data.csv")

C:\Users\nasif\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    653                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    654 
--> 655         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    656 
    657     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\Users\nasif\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    403 
    404     # Create the parser.
--> 405     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    406 
    407     if chunksize or iterator:

C:\Users\nasif\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    760             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    761 
--> 762         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    763 
    764     def close(self):

C:\Users\nasif\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _make_engine(self, engine)
    964     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
    965         if engine == 'c':
--> 966             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
    967         else:
    968             if engine == 'python':

C:\Users\nasif\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1580         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1581 
-> 1582         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1583 
   1584         # XXX

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:4209)()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:8873)()

IOError: File C:/Users/nasif/Desktop/ashik_Thesis/wbpc_data.csv does not exist.
```

Comment: Are you sure "wbpc_data.csv" exists in the mentioned destination?

Comment: yes i am sure.is there any problem in conversion is process .

Comment: For Window's paths, the following approach is often used `r"C:\Users\nasif\Desktop\ashik_Thesis\wbpc_data.csv"` although it will unlikely change the outcome. To ensure no typing issues, try right clicking on the file in Windows whilst pressing `Shift` and then using `Copy as path` to copy the correct path to the clipboard. Then try using that in your code. Note, adding `r` before the string ensures any backslashes are not escaped.

Comment: thanks solved..file name was wpbc_data.csv